# Upwork is not running on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

In the morning `upwork` was working fine, But after lunch time i run `sudo apt-get update` command 
after that it is showing an error

```
Error Message: THERE WAS A PROBLEM LOADING UPWORK
```

Please Help[image]

Comment: What is "upwork"?

Comment: @muru Upwork is a Freelance marketplace company.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Downloading the **libnss3** package and installing it will resolve this issue. Just type the commands given below one-by-one in terminal to download and install **libnss3** :-

*64-bit*

```
wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/233346181/libnss3_3.19.2.1-0ubuntu0.14.04.2_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i libnss3_3.19.2.1-0ubuntu0.14.04.2_amd64.deb
```

*32-bit*

```
wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/233346229/libnss3_3.19.2.1-0ubuntu0.14.04.2_i386.deb

sudo dpkg -i libnss3_3.19.2.1-0ubuntu0.14.04.2_amd64.deb
```

**Another method** to resolve this issue is downloading and installing of the **beta desktop app of Upwork** instead of stable one on Ubuntu.

**Helpful links**

[Installing Upwork Team App on Ubuntu](https://salmanwahed.com/127/installing-upwork-on-ubuntu-xenial-xerus/)

[Linux Troubleshooting for Upwork Team App](https://support.upwork.com/hc/en-us/articles/211064108-Linux-Troubleshooting-for-Upwork-Team-App&lc=en-IN&s=1&m=789&host=www.google.co.in&ts=1478783185&sig=AF9NednBi-zMD1NS1gDyp9oe7T1dYp1niA)